# converting string to URL in PHP

Tags: php, html, regex, url, anchor

I have a string in php and I want to convert it into a URL,Basically I am taking input from the user so I am not sure either he write `http://www.google.com` or just `www.google.com` or maybe just `google.com`, In either cases I have to show him the URL link in an anchor tag.
I am looking for any PHP function that can do this,
Otherwise I have to manually search for `http` and other If else condition will surely gonna waste my time,If there is no function I would be more than happy to write one and make it open to the community.
**EDIT:**
Another thing is the best way to write HTML in PHP, I mean is it good if we use echo' long HTML Forms' etc
any solution
Thanks

Comment: if you put any of this string as a source of url it will work. also remember that subdomains don't use `www` on start. if you want to have http:// on start check if string contains `http://`. if not add this if yes don't

Comment: @Fixus sounds like a good solution , can you see the update I made to question thanks

Comment: there is no best way it dependes on your solution. i never echo it i return in after parsing in template engine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are looking for parse_url

http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php

Comment: thank you but this is not what I am looking for, it just parses your string

Answer (score 7):

you can still use parse_url function

```
$parsed = parse_url($urlStr);
if (empty($parsed['scheme'])) {
    $urlStr = 'http://' . ltrim($urlStr, '/');
}
```

about writing html with PHP, it's okay to use echo function, just make sure you escape the double quotes with backslash

Answer (score 0):

Use the substr() functoin for existence of HTTP and if not present add HTTP, put the string as Href in the anchor tag.Surely gonna work

Comment: what if the user put some link to an HTTPS site?

Comment: @user1765876 you have to take care of both conditions

Answer (score 0):

You can use [parse_url()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php) who will try to  parse input into part.
And you just have to check if "scheme" is here to know how to complete url.

If you want to validate input, you can use [filter_var()](http://php.net/manual/en/filter.filters.validate.php) with FILTER_VALIDATE_URL option

```
filter_var($input, FILTER_VALIDATE_URL) ) ? echo "Valid url" : echo "invalid url";
```